# Firestore returns data where none is expected

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore query in a stream on flutter that returns data where none is expected. The code is as follows:

```
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  String userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
  CollectionReference school = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('schools');

  Stream<School> get schoolData async* {
    yield* school
        .where('currentAdmin', isEqualTo: userId)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
      (documents) {
        return documents == null
            ? null
            : School.fromJson(
                documents.docs.first.id,
                documents.docs.first.data(),
              );
      },
    );
  }
```

The user is not logged in and therefore the `userId` is `null` but the query returns data. Also, when I comment out `.where('currentAdmin', isEqualTo: userId)`, I am getting results showing that the filter is being ignored.

How can this be edited to return a school where the currentAdmin is the userId of the logged in user?

Answer (score 1):

I think because you are asking for snapshots it is returning a snapshot rather than documents which will not return null even if there are no documents in that snapshot.

Something to try: Instead of checking if documents == null, try the built-in null check...  `return documents.docs.isNotEmpty ? ... : no documents`

Edit: also check the user is logged in before you send the query.

```
if(user != null){
  Stream<School> get schoolData async* {
      yield* school
          .where('currentAdmin', isEqualTo: userId)
          .snapshots()
          .map(
        (documents) {
          return documents.docs.isEmpty
              ? null
              : School.fromJson(
                  documents.docs.first.id,
                  documents.docs.first.data(),
                );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```